# Ajax call using XmlHttp to struts getting null values in request parameter in jboss server

Tags: ajax, jboss5.x, struts-1

I'm confused with this problem.Actually my code is working fine in weblogic server but when i try with jboss5 server, It didn't work.Kindly help me to resolve this.

My problem is,I'm calling one struts action from ajax script using XmlHttp and passing some parameter.when i try to retrive the parameter in struts action class,it return null value.

This is my code:
Ajax-scrpt:

```
var params = (inpVal != '' && outVal != '' && oprAction != '') ? 'inReturn='+tmpStr+'&ouReturn='+outVal+'&Operation_Scr='+oprAction : null;

XmlHttp.onreadystatechange = HandleResponseFromServer;
        XmlHttp.open("POST", sUrl,  true);
        XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=iso-8859-9");
        XmlHttp.send(params);
```

If i print params here,Every values are come perfectly.
struts config:

```
 <action  path="/ajax-action"
            type="com.amgen.devis.gmat.util.AjaxAction"
            name="StudyDesignAssignmentForm" input="/mainCDM.jsp" scope="request" validate="false">
              <forward name="success"  path="/content/AjaxOutPut.jsp" contextRelative="true"/>
 </action>
```

And my action class:
If I print here null value occur

```
System.out.println("Operation Type:  "+(String)request.getParameter("Operation_Scr"));
```

It returns null value.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Why are you setting `Content-Type` twice? Why not leave the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and test if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You setting your `Content-Type` twice on your HTTP request header. This, essentially, overrides the `Content-Type` with the last value it receives.

The solution is to use set your `Content-Type` as follows:

```
XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-9");
XmlHttp.send(params);
```

Note that I have included the `charset` into the parameter value.